# Find Earliest Transaction Date when using Transaction Date in "WHERE" clause

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

I'm creating a daily report for transactions that happened the day before on purchase (both new and previous).  For simplicity, it looks like:

```
SELECT 
Table.Identifier as 'Number',
Table.Name as 'Customer Name',
Table.PurchaseDate as 'Date',
sum(Table.Amount) as 'Amount',
Case 
when 'SOME CODE' then 'NEW'
when sum(Table.Amount) > 0 then 'INC'
when sum(Table.Amount) < 0 then 'DEC'
end case as 'Transaction Type'
Where
Table.TransactionEntryDate = DATEADD(DAY, CASE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 
                        WHEN 1 THEN -2 
                        WHEN 2 THEN -3 
                        ELSE -1 
                    END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))
```

The transaction date is the last business day, (if today's Monday, the last day is Friday) I only want entries with the transaction date as the last business date, but in order to classify it as a `NEW` Transaction Type, I need to see if today's transaction date is the minimum transaction date for the `Identifier / Number`. but as the `WHERE` clause already filters out all the non-required dates, any clause I put in the `'SOME CODE'` spot of the `CASE` clause will return `NEW`

ie if we consider the two cases

Transaction Identifier #1 occurs some days ago, but a return transaction and an another purchase was made the prior business day. (We care about net transaction) There are therefore 2 entries in the Table.  I want the CASE function to see that the minimum (ie first) Entry Date is NOT the prior business day and continue on to "DEC" case.

Transaction Identifier #5 occurs the prior business day.  This is the first entry in the Table. I want the case function to recognize that Identifier #5's earliest Entry Date is the prior business date so the CASE function assigns Transaction Type as NEW.

[image: sample table described above]

However, I can't use a count function as sometimes there are multiple transactions for the same identifier on the same day and I want them summed. Sometimes the "Purchase Date" is different than the transaction date, as orders are pre-ordered prior to the actual transaction, so I can't just do `when PurchaseDate = TransactionEntryDate`

Here is what I'd like the table to look like.  However as the Identifier #1 has the Feb-25 Transaction filtered out, a when `when min(Table.TransactionEntryDate) = Table.TransactionEntryDate` `then 'NEW'` will also return 'NEW'

[image: desired outcome]

Something like this, (but it doesn't work in my query)

```
when min(All Table.TransactionEntryDate where Table.identifier= Table.Identifier AND Table.PurchaseDate= Table.PurchaseDate) = DATEADD(DAY, CASE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 
                        WHEN 1 THEN -2 
                        WHEN 2 THEN -3 
                        ELSE -1 
                    END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())) then 'NEW'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this'll identify for each row if an earlier row exists:

```
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) Identifier
             FROM Table T1
             WHERE T1.Identifier = Table.Identifier
             AND T1.TransactionEntryDate < Table.TransactionEntryDate) AS PriorTransactionExists
```

And then in your case:

```
CASE WHEN PriorTransactionExists.Identifier IS NULL THEN 'NEW'
```

You could probably just do it as an inline exists instead of the outer apply? Hopefully I've understood but apologies if not.

EDIT AFTER REALISING THIS IS MYSQL:

```
Case when not exists (SELECT 1 FROM Table T1
             WHERE T1.Identifier = Table.Identifier
             AND T1.TransactionEntryDate < Table.TransactionEntryDate) THEN 'New'
```

Comment: I'm definitely down to try this! (and I'm not the best explainer) but I have no idea where to add this to my query, I'm a beginner SQL but know the basics.

Comment: Ahh, I've just spotted this is mysql, should have looked closer.  I'm afraid this probably won't be applicable.  Will edit response in a sec.